# How to modify system key events' behavior in Android

Tags: android

Following [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#java) I have created a simple admin app that asks the user to enable the system admin app. I want to lock the app so that the user cannot exit the app once they have agreed to allow system app (useful for kiosk devices).

I see no API for locking the app in the way described. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;
    private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = findViewById(R.id.enable_admin);

        // Prepare to work with the DPM
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mDeviceAdmin  = new ComponentName(this, MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Launch the activity to have the user enable our admin.
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdmin);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                        "We need admin access");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                // return false - don't update checkbox until we're really active

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 100) {
            mDPM.lockNow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Calling `lockNow()` immediately locks the device and turns off the display (Far from what I want). How can I implement kiosk lock down for my app?
Let's assume the user enables my app as system admin. Then, how can I intercept system keys like Home button, and Settings (on remote controllers), to prevent the user from exiting the application?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by the following code

```
 String[] packages=new String[1];
            packages[0]="yourpackagename";
            devicePolicyManager.isLockTaskPermitted(packages[0]);
            startLockTask();//enabling kiosk mode
```

Comment: This does not work as it requires user interaction to pin the app. I'm looking for a way to do it automatically. The app is administrator. So, there must be a way to do this.